# Alarm service start automatically when i open spinner Activity

Tags: java, android

I have a spinner class in which has three spinner item, in each item case I set a time interval for repeating alarm.Problem is every time I open spinner class, the in-app service start automatically but I want service to start only when I change spinner item not every time when I open spinner class. 
here is java code for spinner item.

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_setting, container, false);
        textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        spinner = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                getActivity(), R.array.time_interval, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);       adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                                       View view, int pos, long id){
               // String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
               // Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                Object test = parent.getSelectedItem();
                switch (pos){
                    case 0:
                        break;
                case 1:
                    editor.putInt("intervalInMinutes", 5*60*1000);
                break;
                    case 2 :
                    editor.putInt("intervalInMinutes", 10*60*1000);
                        break;
                    case 3 :
                    editor.putInt("intervalInMinutes", 15*60*1000);
                        break;
                }
                editor.apply();
                GpsTrackerAlarmReceiver alarm = new GpsTrackerAlarmReceiver();
                alarm.setAlarm(getActivity());
                }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
            }
        });
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return rootView;
    }
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("prefs_name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        prefs.edit().putInt("spinner_indx", spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()).apply();
    }
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("prefs_name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        int spinnerIndx = prefs.getInt("spinner_indx", 0);
        spinner.setSelection(spinnerIndx);
    }
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        //noinspection deprecation
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }
    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a bool flag ,because your spinner listener will get called first time automatically while creation and hence your alarm code will be executed so you need to put a check to execute the alarm code only on selection .

```
 SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
int previousitm =sharedPreferences.getInt("previousItemselected",0);


boolean flag =false;
        switch (pos){
            case 0:
                break;
        case 1:
            if(previousitm!=1)
                flag=true;
            editor.putInt("intervalInMinutes", 5*60*1000);
            editor.putInt("previousItemselected",1);
        break;
            case 2 :
            if(previousitm!=2)
                flag=true;
            editor.putInt("intervalInMinutes", 10*60*1000);
            editor.putInt("previousItemselected",2);
                break;
            case 3 :
            if(previousitm!=3)
                flag=true;
            editor.putInt("intervalInMinutes", 15*60*1000);
            editor.putInt("previousItemselected",3);
                break;
        }
        editor.apply();
        if(flag){
          GpsTrackerAlarmReceiver alarm = new GpsTrackerAlarmReceiver();
          alarm.setAlarm(getActivity());
        }
        }
```

Comment: my pleasure and happy coding